# Is there a valid reason why nn.CDivTable throws error when backward is called?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, torch

I've recently started playing with neural networks using Torch framework and Lua scripting language. I've got the basics with linear networks, so I tried something more complex but simple enough:

the idea is that I have 3 inputs, I have to choose first two, divide them, and forward the result to linear module. So, I've made this little script:

```
require "nn";
require "optim";

local N = 3;

local input = torch.Tensor{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {9, 20, 20},
    {9, 300, 1},
};

local output = torch.Tensor(N);
for i=1, N do
    output[i] = 1;
end

local ratioPerceptron = nn.Sequential();
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Narrow(1, 1, 2));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.CDivTable());
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Reshape(N, 1));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Linear(1, 1));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid());

local criterion = nn.BCECriterion();
local params, gradParams = ratioPerceptron:getParameters();
local optimState = {learningRate = 0.01};

local maxIteration = 100000;
for i=1, maxIteration do
    local function f(params)
        gradParams:zero();

        local outputs = ratioPerceptron:forward(input);
        local loss = criterion:forward(outputs, output);
        local dloss_doutputs = criterion:backward(outputs, output);
        ratioPerceptron:backward(input, dloss_doutputs);

        return loss, gradParams;
    end

    optim.sgd(f, params, optimState);
end
```

This fails when backward is called during training with error:

> CDivTable.lua:21: both torch.LongStorage and (null) have no addition operator

But if I remove CDivTable from sequential module, and change nn.Reshape and nn.Linear to two-dimensional input (since we removed CDivTable which divides two-dim input to produce one-dim output) like this:

```
local ratioPerceptron = nn.Sequential();
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Narrow(1, 1, 2));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Reshape(N, 2));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Linear(2, 1));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid());
```

Training finishes without error... Is there any other way to divide two selected inputs and forward the result to the linear module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `CDivTable` take a table as input and divides the elements of the first table by the ones of the second table. Here you feed your network with as single input, and not a table of two input. That is why you have an error with `null` I believe. Torch is unable to understand that your input (which consists in two vectors) should be considered as a table of two vectors. It only sees a tensor of size `2x3`! Therefore you have to tell Torch to create a table from the input. Therefore you can use the module `SplitTable(dim)` that will split the input into tables along the dimension `dim`.

Insert this line `ratioPerceptron:add(nn.SplitTable(1))` after the narrow module:

```
local ratioPerceptron = nn.Sequential();
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Narrow(1, 1, 2));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.SplitTable(1))
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.CDivTable());
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Reshape(N, 1));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Linear(1, 1));
ratioPerceptron:add(nn.Sigmoid());
```

Besides, when you have such errors I suggest you looking at what is computed by your network by putting `print` statements: insert a line `print(ratioPerceptron:forward(input))` before the line where you add a module that creates an error.